# Getting a field from a table that is not in the left outer join in the same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 4 tables, 3 of which are joined, but I need to get a field from the forth table (Table_D). For the sake of simplicity lets say they are Tables A, B, C, D.

```
Select Distinct A.Field_1, B.Field_2, C.Field_3
From Table_A
Left outer join B on A.Field_z= B.Field_z
Left Outer Join C on A.Field_z= C.Field_z
where A.Field_z in (1111);
```

This seems to work but I need a field in Table_D that is only connected to Table_A through Table_C.

How can I add it to the join? or can I?

Thanks!

WB

Comment: What have you tried?  You should be able to join it just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `on` clause has essentially all the features of the `where` clause. `on` clauses for any part of the join can refer to any attribute of any entity in the `from` clause, I suspect your confusion comes from thinking that you can only join subsequent entities to the first entity in the `from` clause. If `Table_D` is related to `Table_A` through `Table_C`, you might see a `from`/`join`/`on` construct like:

```
select a.thing, b.things, c.thang, d.stuff
from Table_A a
 left join Table_B b
  on a.id = b.a_id
 left join Table_C c
  on a.id = c.a_id
 left join Table D d
  on d.id = c.d_id
where
  a.this = b.that
```

Note that the word "outer" is implied in a left join, and is not necessary for syntactic completion.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped me to produce the query I needed. I am now using it everyday. This is the first time I have used stackoverflow to ask a question so I presume I just hit the check mark. Please let me know if I need to do anything else. Thanks to all who replied!

Comment: the green checkmark is it! if you're feeling extra generous, the up arrow helps my reputation as well.

Comment: happy i could help

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can add it.  You don't specify the logic, but something like this:

```
Select Distinct A.Field_1, B.Field_2, C.Field_3, D.??
From Table_A a Left outer join
     B
     on A.Field_z= B.Field_z Left Outer Join
     C
     on A.Field_z= C.Field_z Left Outer Join
     D
     on . . . 
where A.Field_z in (1111);
```

Just fill in the conditions that you want.  You want a `left join`, because the condition between `c` and `d` would otherwise turn the outer join to `c` into an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I believe this would work:

```
Left Outer Join D on C.Field_z= D.Field_z
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. It will help i guess

```
Select Distinct A.Field_1, B.Field_2, C.Field_3, c.Field_4
From Table_A
Left outer join B on A.Field_z= B.Field_z
Left Outer Join  ( select C.field_3, d.Field_4, c.Field_z from c inner join d on c.field_z = d.field_z ) c on A.Field_z= C.Field_z
where A.Field_z in (1111);
```